# Uncaught ReferenceError: Polymer is not defined after event.preventDefault()

Tags: polymer

I am getting the following error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Polymer is not defined
```

when I click on the link on the following element:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="bower_components/platform/platform.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <my-element id="my_element"></my-element>
</body>
</html>

<link rel="import" href="bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
<polymer-element name="my-element">
    <template>
        <a href="#" on-tap="{{linkClicked}}">my link</a>
    </template>
    <script>
        Polymer('my-element', {
            linkClicked: function(event, detail, sender) {
                event.preventDefault();
            }
        });
    </script>
</polymer-element>
```

Is this a Polymer bug or am I doing something wrong?

http://jsbin.com/cuxep/1/edit?html,output

Comment: Have you noticed the structure of your markup is not correct? You are defining a custom element AFTER you close the <html>. This could be affecting things.

Comment: Actually, I have the html and custom element on separate files, but pasted them here to show them together.

Comment: The problem has something to do with href="#" attribute on the a element; it seems that Polymer can't handle the "#" value.

Comment: I see, thought i'd clarify that. I'm not able to reproduce your javascript error. What browser and version are you running? It seems `event.preventDefault()` does not work as expected for the 'tap' event, but that's probably a different issue.

Comment: chromium 34 on ubuntu & chrome 35 on win7

Comment: Another weird thing about this, Polymer seems to be overwriting the href attribute on the anchor element to the empty string at runtime.

Answer (score 2):

As @badsyntax points out above, it looks like event.preventDefault() doesn't work well for the tap event. Changing to `on-click` seems to solve the problem of preventing a navigation though.

The error that you saw:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Polymer is not defined
```

That seems to be an artifact of malformed HTML, I suspect this was causing a race condition between loading `polymer.html` and your `<script>` element being executed. After cleaning up the HTML I was no longer able to reproduce it.

Here's a jsbin that works as I believe you intend: http://jsbin.com/boweliwe/1/edit

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>

<script>console.clear()</script>
<script src="//www.polymer-project.org/components/platform/platform.js"></script>
<link rel="import" href="//www.polymer-project.org/components/polymer/polymer.html">

<my-element></my-element>

<polymer-element name="my-element">
<template>
  <a href='#' on-click="{{linkClicked}}">my link</a>
</template>
<script>
  Polymer('my-element', {
    linkClicked: function(event, detail, sender) {
      event.preventDefault();
    }
  });
</script>
</polymer-element>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where do you think the problem is?  Chrome's JavaScript engine?

Comment: No, I believe the on-tap event is generated by the PointerGestures library in Polymer. I've filed a bug: https://github.com/Polymer/PointerGestures/issues/39

Comment: The tap event is actually generated by the polymer-gestures library now. https://github.com/polymer/polymer-gestures/